# what is jquery click() doing in this context?

Tags: jquery

I don't understand what click() is doing in this context:

```
var wallcarousel = _root.find('.wall-carousel').flickity({
            cellAlign: 'center',
            contain: true,
            prevNextButtons: false,
            pageDots: false
        });
        wallcarousel.on( 'select.flickity', function() {
            $('.filter-category.is-selected a').click();
        });
```

Is it turning `.filter-category.is.selected a`  into a clickable object?

Seems redundant to me?

Comment: It's triggering the `click` event on the selected elements

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/click/#click

Comment: Try this in your console on this page ... `$('button.js-close-question-link').click()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will have the same effect as if you clicked on the element with your mouse. So basically an emulated mouse click.